# What is the difference between "x IS NULL" and "NOT (x IS NOT NULL)"?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, arel

Is there a significant difference in postgresql's execution, performance, or logic between

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE ("users"."deleted_at" IS NULL)
```

and

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (NOT ("users"."deleted_at" IS NOT NULL))
```

Obviously, if written by hand, the first expression is the one I would write (who would intentionally write a double negative?!).  But in this case, I'm using ruby's arel library to dynamically create both versions, sort of like so:

```
def generate_query(search_terms, negated=false, users=User)
  where_clause = arel_for_one_of_many_possible_queries(search_terms)
  where_clause = where_clause.not if negated
  users.where(where_clause)
end
```

And, for the `"deleted"` search_term, the `where_clause` will be `arel_table[:deleted_at].not_eq(nil)`, but for other search_terms it could be a variety of clauses, including compound clauses and subselects.  Adding the `.not` to the end, arel will always generate SQL of the second form.  I *could* generate the first form by special casing my `NULL` checks and manually generating `.eq` or `.not_eq` as the case may be, but I'd want some clear benefit to doing that before I make my code more verbose.

Comment: The two WHERE clauses yield the exactly same result. No functional difference. However, the query planner will probably not be able to use an otherwise fitting index on an expression, if you should use that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [EXPLAIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) to see the difference, if there is any.

<strike>I think the query rewriter will optimize this, but I didn't check the source code for this example.</strike>

Edit: I was wrong, this is not optimized at all. Where **("users"."deleted_at" IS NULL)** can use an index, the **(NOT ("users"."deleted_at" IS NOT NULL))** condition results in a sequential disk scan.

Comment: Oops.  Obviously I should check `explain`!  Thanks.  But, just to make things absolutely clear, there is no *logical* different between the two, right?  I sometimes forget what the exact SQL relational algebra rules are for handling NULL equality which can lead to some unfortunate surprises.

Comment: FWIW, postgresql 8.4.9's query rewriter does not seem to be rewriting this for me.  So I'll need to test it with production data to see if it makes a significant performance difference.

Comment: Could you show us the differences between the two queryplans?